# Mysql not started after some crash

Tags: mysql, linux

I don't know what exactly happen, but I can't start mysql over lamp controller. In console I can do it, but mysql is not started in fact. Here is my login file. Can some experienced look at it?

```
2018-08-21 13:07:47 15345 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with
databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] Using unique option prefix 
key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the
full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld
10.1.32-MariaDB) starting as process 15487 ...

2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] InnoDB:
innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of
small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at
least up to 20MB.

2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref
count buffer pool pages
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap
is disabled
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks
use GCC atomic builtins
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin
__sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier

2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use
zlib 1.2.8
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer
pool, size = 32.0M
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [Note] InnoDB: Completed
initialization of buffer pool
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [ERROR] InnoDB: /opt/lampp/var/mysql
ib_logfile1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function
returned error.
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration
as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/opt/lampp
var/mysql/aria_log.00000001' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
free(): invalid pointer
180821 13:07:47 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly
built, or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.32-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
137051 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x48400
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x24)[0xbfee44]
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x57a)[0x764e9a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890)[0x7f7cce495890]
linux/raise.c:51(__GI_raise)[0x7f7cccc5de97]
stdlib/abort.c:81(__GI_abort)[0x7f7cccc5f801]
posix/libc_fatal.c:181(__libc_message)[0x7f7cccca8897]
malloc/malloc.c:5350(_IO_str_seekoff)[0x7f7ccccaf90a]
malloc/malloc.c:4157(_int_free)[0x7f7ccccb6e1c]
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld[0xaea9a5]
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld[0xad4e25]
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x63)
[0x768b33]
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld[0x5d1c5c]
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xc74)[0x5d5364]
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld[0x5327dc]
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x4b6)[0x533716]
csu/libc-start.c:344(__libc_start_main)[0x7f7cccc40b97]
/opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld[0x527eb9]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2018-08-21 13:07:47 15345 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp
var/mysql/solutac3.pid ended
```

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/80749/150107

Comment: I haven't folder data in mysql and in log is not anything about it. My OS is Linux Mint

Comment: Folder and filename are listed in your log in the first [ERROR] line: `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/` and `ib_logfile1` respectively.

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: Consider changing key_buffer to key_buffer_size in your my.cnf [mysqld] section. The message will go away warning of possible break in future.

Comment: @hot2use I used snapshot of timeshift from that day and everything was good.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the important part:

```
2018-08-21 13:07:47 140174025643840 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/opt/lampp
var/mysql/aria_log.00000001' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
free(): invalid pointer
```

It says, that it can't get access to `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/aria_log.00000001`, which seems for me to be some transaction log file.

Give them permission to everything in `/opt/lampp/var/mysql`.